# Component id not found in JSF while doing JUnit testing

Tags: java, jsf, junit

I am creating the Junit testcases for jsf beans please find below is the code.

```
public void createKey(final ActionEvent event)
{
LOGGER.info("CreateKeyBean createKey method called...");
final long moduleIdLong = Long.parseLong(moduleid);

try {
    labeldbservice.createKey(moduleIdLong, key);
    labeldbservice.saveTranslation(null, moduleIdLong, Locale.ENGLISH.toString(), key, text);

    FacesMessageUtil.addStatusMessage(LabeldbUtils.CREATE_TOP_PANEL, LabeldbUtils.CREATE_KEY_LABEL, null);

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
    FacesMessageUtil.addGlobalUnexpectedErrorMessage();
    FacesMessageUtil.addStatusMessage(LabeldbUtils.CREATE_TOP_PANEL, LabeldbUtils.ERROR_LABEL_MSG, null);
}
}
```

I am testing the above method after calling the service i am sending the status message to UI with component id(FacesMessageUtil.addStatusMessage(''')).

My Question is : while calling this method :FacesMessageUtil.addStatusMessage(''')) i am getting the exception saying component id not found , 
could you please help me how to set component ID from JUnit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Component Id's are generated by JSF Framework.
If you are using core JUnit to test the methods which deals with the component Ids,who is generating the IDs.
That's why Testing the JSF application is hardest part.
Scenarios like this require frameworks which are more than a JUnit like [JSFUnit](https://www.jboss.org/jsfunit).